# Disable automatic iTunes music stop when switching to Youtube on iPad

Tags: itunes, youtube, ipad

I am listening to some music on my iPad, from iTunes. Sometimes I switch to the youtube app, because I want to just watch some scientific videos (mostly text and images, no sound or useless music), but then and automatically, music from iTunes stops! How can I disable this?

Comment: I am not sure if you can overlay itunes music with youtube music.. even though you dont want the youtube one.. i think only 1 audio source can play at a time.. regardless if its muted or not.. but maybe there is hack.. not sure.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I am afraid there is no solution is this black-box apple world ...

Comment: @flow, there may be a way if you **jailbreak** your device. You could try asking [JailbreakQA](http://www.jailbreakqa.com/).